# Incremental Data copy for Postgres DB using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement, where i need to copy incremental data from one postgres DB to another postgres DB.

I thought i will use watermark column approach and then use look up and for each to achieve this , however problem comes because in postgres database sink , i don't get an option for upsert .

any idea how i can achieve incremental data load , if my target is postgres DB?

I created a pipelien with watermark look and used foreach to copy the data , however i am not sure what to do when sink is Postgress DB, I don't have upsert option avaiable

Answer (score 0):

There is no upsert option in azure SQL database for PostgreSQL sink dataset. For inserting the new records in the sink, you can follow the same approach you followed. In order to update the changes of the existing records, you can delete the existing record and insert the record in the sink. Below is the detailed approach.

- Source table and target table are taken as in below image.
  [image]
- Watermark table is created, and its initial value is given as  `1900-01-01`.

[image]

- Then in ADF, lookup activity is taken and source dataset in the lookup activity is for watermark table.

[image]

- Again lookup activity is taken to take values of id field (primary key column) from the source table. This is done because if the same ids are there in sink, those rows are to be deleted and new rows for those ids are to be inserted.

[image]

Query in Lookup2:

```sql
select distinct id from src_employee where created_date> '@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.watermark_column}'
```

- The result of lookup2 is stored in a variable v1 of string type using set variable activity.

[image]

- Another variable v2 is set using set variable activity. Value for variable v2 is given as `@{replace(replace(replace(replace(variables('v1'),'{"id":',''),'}',''),'[','('),']',')')}`.
  This expression removes the characters `"{"id":`, `"}"` and replaces the characters  `[`,`]`  with `(`, `)` respectively.

[image]

- Then copy activity is taken and in source dataset, query is given as,

```sql
select distinct id from src_employee where created_date> '@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.watermark_column}'
```

- In sink dataset settings, sink dataset is given and pre-copy activity is written as

```sql
delete from tgt_employee where id in @{variables('v2')}
```

- Then you can update the watermark table with the new value using lookup activity or script activity based on the dataset you store the watermark table.

```sql
update watermark_table
set watermark_column=(select max(created_date) from tgt_employee)
```

**Result:**

1. When pipeline is run for the first time, data is copied from source to sink and watermark_column of watermark_table is updated as  `2023-04-26 00:00:00.0000000`
2. Then data is changed in the source table. Row with id=3 is updated and new row with id=5 is inserted.
   [image]

[image]

[image]

Data is changed in sink table as per source.